# Add a span tag inside p after certain amount of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose you have this for your HTML:

```
<div class="contentBox"> 
    <p>I have some content that is good to read</p>
</div>
```

However you would like to add a span tag after a certain amount of characters, lets say 26 characters, which would be right after the word "that".  The result would look like this:

```
<div class="contentBox">
    <p>I have some content that<span> is good to read</span></p>
</div>
```

It has to be after a certain amount of characters, because the paragraph will change from time to time.

Comment: You cannot achieve this safely without looking out for HTML tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the amount of characters after you want to set the `span`. Get text of the `p` element. Substring from start until the amount of chars, add the `span`, continue with the rest and add the closing `span`

Try:

```
var after=26;
var html = $(".contentBox p").html();
html = html.substring(0, after) + "<span>" + html.substring(after)+"</span>";
$(".contentBox p").html(html);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7yr0o87x/1/)**

Comment: Just be aware that this may result in nesting of tags, and possibly invalid code, if the paragraph contains anything else but pure text (no HTML or such).

Comment: @OskarLindberg Indeed you are correct. For the specific HTML markup  of the OP will work. For other markups(with nested elements) will not

Comment: Thanks, works fine and yeah it will only have pure text for what I need it for.

Comment: @laaposto Yes, I'm not saying your answer is "wrong". It's just meant as a heads-up kind of comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.prototype.insertTextAtIndices = function (text) {
    return this.replace(/./g, function (char, index) {
        return text[index] ? text[index] + char : char;
    });
};
//usage
var range = {
    25: "<span style='color:red'>",
    40: "</span>"
};

document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML.insertTextAtIndices(range);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zx37Lhm/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [JavaScript's `substr` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

```js
function addSpan($elems) {
  $elems.each(function() {
      var $elem = $(this),
          text = $elem.text();

      if (text.length <= 25)
        return;

      var start = text.substr(0, 25),         // "I have some content that "
          end = text.substr(25, text.length); // "is good to read"

      $elem.html(start + '<span>' + end + '</span>');
  });
}

addSpan($('.contentBox').find('p'));
```

```css
span {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentBox"> 
  <p>I have some content that is good to read</p>
</div>

<div class="contentBox"> 
  <p>I have some content that is good to read and this is a much longer string!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will clear out any HTML tags within the paragraph, that is, all existing formatting and structure.

Comment: @OskarLindberg that is true, however I based this answer entirely on the details OP has given in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying your answer is "wrong". It's just meant as a heads-up kind of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : get first part and second part of the string using `substring()` and modify text with `span` element to put it into `html` of `p` tag.

Below function will iterate all `p` under `contentBox` div, but if you are targeting only one div then you can use it without `.each()`

```
$(function(){
    $('.contentBox p').each(function(){
      var text = $(this).text();
      var first = text.substring(0,26);
      var second = text.substring(26,text.length);
      $(this).html(first + '<span>' + second + '</span>');  
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xj4xhfg7/3/)**

Comment: Just be aware that this will clear out any HTML tags within the paragraph, that is, all existing formatting and structure.