# Implanting string into html page (Challenging)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to create a method which achieves the following:
Implanting a string (For example: `"TEST"`) into the body of an HTML page, every certain number of words (10 for instance). This problem is complicated by the fact that the word count must carry over between elements.
For example, the following HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>My Day at the Park</h1>
<p>I had a great day at the park today.</p>
<p>It was very fun, and I would like to go again soon.</p>
</body>
```

Should become:

```
<body>
<h1>My Day at the Park</h1>
<p>I had a great dayTEST at the park today.</p>
<p>It was very fun, and ITEST would like to go again soon.</p>
</body>
```

Accordingly, `"TEST"` was inserted after every 10th word ("day" and "I"). The first counted word is "My" and the last is "soon.".
A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377583/add-a-span-tag-inside-p-after-certain-amount-of-characters) has been asked in the past, though that question does not address the vital issue of continuity between elements (as mentioned in the comments by Oskar Lindberg).

**My (failed) approach to solving this problem was by the following process:**
1. Using jQuery `$('body').text()` to obtain all text in body. 2. Using `.split(' ')` to create array of all words. 3. Counting and recording every 10th word in a new array: `cutoffWords[]`. 4. Counting the number of times each cutoff word occurs before the occurance in which it is a cutoff word (10th word). 5. Running through `$('body').html`, and injecting the string after the cuttoff word on its cutoff occurance.

I can post the actual code, which is long, if requested, but this method suffers from an ihereint flaw, in that when running through `$('body').html`, text inside element tags are also counted, so that it can result in the misplacement of the string (or placement inside of an element tag).

As a novice JavaScript programmer I am at my whit's end, and will appreciate any advice.

Comment: You do know you need the opening `<span>` tag as well, right?

Comment: @PHPglue It is valid in an xhtml docuement with correct mimetype, but I have changed it for clarity.

Comment: I am working on a solution for you, so far I have been able to split the body element text into an array of strings using `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children).map(child => child.innerHTML)` (`.text` was returning undefined for your example HTML)and am working on the loop to add your `</span>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the previous answer from Gerardo BLANCO is almost perfect. If you want to have some more control over the elements that are really handled (e.g., if a `<script>`-tag would appear in your code, it would also be counted) and if you want to also support nested elements, the following may help.

```js
var validTypes = ['h1', 'p', 'div', 'span'];
var pos = 10;
var addedText = 'TEST';
var counter = 0;

var splitter = function ($el) {

    $el.contents().each(function () {
        var $innerEl = $(this);

        if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var text = $innerEl.text().trim();
            if (text !== '') {
                var content = text.replace(/ +/g, ' ').split(' ');
                var newText = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                    newText += ' ' + content[i];

                    if (++counter === pos) {
                        newText += addedText;
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }

                this.nodeValue = newText;
            }
        } else if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && 
                   validTypes.indexOf(this.tagName.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            splitter($innerEl);
        }
    })
};

splitter($('body'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>My Day at the Park</h1>
    <script>// do nothing here just ignore me</script>
    <p>I had a great day at <span style='color:red'>the</span> park today.</p>
    <p>It was very fun, and I would like to go again soon.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tested your solution on several article length web pages and it thus far seems to work flawlessly. Great job!

Answer (score 1):

Awesome challenge

Ok lets start,
First of all i need to insert everything in a div because the scipts counted as the body children. If this doesnt work for you, we can make a work around.

I made a var `current` this var will keep count of how many words we have gone through

I get all the childrens div and loop between them. Then i split the childrens word and count them

If the count + current is bigger than 10, then we need to add an element.
If not, then current gets the count added

Hope this helps :)

```js
let current = 0;
$('div').children().each(function() {
  let words = $(this).text().split(" ");
  if (current + words.length < 10) {
    current += words.length;
  } else {
    let diff = 10 - current;
    words[diff - 1] = words[diff - 1].concat("TEST");
    this.innerHTML = words.join(" ");
    current = words.length - diff;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>My Day at the Park</h1>
    <p>I had a great day at the park today.</p>
    <p>It was very fun, and I would like to go again soon.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Short and efficient I will likely choose Phillip's answer as correct because it treats a broader range of circumstances, although in all fairness to you I never mentioned nested elements in my question. Still a great method.

Comment: the most elegant solution by far.

Answer (score 0):

Watch and Learn

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, M, I, S, Q, addTextAfterEvery, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
addTextAfterEvery = function(text, wordCount, withinSelector){
  var wi = withinSelector || 'body';
  var all = Q(wi+' *');
  for(var i=0,e,aa=[],l=all.length; i<l; i++){
    e = all[i]; aa.push(e.innerHTML.split(/(?!:\S)\s+(?!:\S)/));
  }
  for(var i=0,w=0,a,r=[],l=aa.length; i<l; i++){
    a = aa[i];
    for(var n=0,q=a.length; n<q; n++){
      if(++w%wordCount === 0)a[n] += text;
    }
    r.push(a.join(' '));
  }
  for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
    all[i].innerHTML = r[i];
  }
}
addTextAfterEvery('TEST', 10, '.main');
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>addTextAfterEvery</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <h1>My Day at the Park</h1>
    <p>I had a great day at the park today.</p>
    <p>It was very fun, and I would like to go again soon.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```